# Can I use a .gitignore with a bare repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a bare repo that I setup using

```
git init --bare
```

It also has a simple post-receive hook like this that updates the web application.

```
git --work-tree=/foo/public_html --git-dir=/foo/root.git checkout -f
```

I want to also push to github but I did not want to push my entire repo.

```
git push github_repo
```

I wanted to use a .gitignore file in the root directory that ignores all my php files:

```
*.php
```

Can I do it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to also push to github but I did not want to push my entire repo.
>
> ```
> git push github_repo
> ```
>
> I wanted to use a .gitignore file in the root directory that ignores all my php files:
>
> ```
> *.php
> ```
>
> Can I do it this way?

No.

Git's ignore system *prevents files from being tracked*. In other words, ignored files are never added to the repository at all. The ignore system *has no effect on tracked files*, so by the time the files reach your repository (bare or otherwise) they're no longer ignorable.

> Currently the .gitignore in root is ignoring files on my client machine that pushes to the bare repo ( server ).

This works because it prevents the files from being tracked in the first place.

Comment: Can I do a `git push` from my bare repo at all?

Comment: @cadegalt, yes. From your bare repository use `git remote add` to add a remote as usual, then push.

Comment: Well, then I could just create a .gitignore in my bare repo and it would use it, right?

Comment: @cadegalt, no. Your bare repository is *only* the repository (the stuff that lives inside `.git/` in a non-bare repository). There is no working copy, so you can't have untracked content. Everything in a bare repository is tracked, and Git's ignores have no impact on tracked files.

Comment: Thanks, @cadegalt. I have read Pro Git (and a number of other resources), and I've used Git for many years. Lots of what I know just comes from experience. I also found [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) to be very useful. It explains how Git works internally, which really helps a lot of the surface-level stuff to make more sense. Good luck!

Comment: You can absolutely use a .gitignore file with a bare repo. Indeed, .gitignore files don't really have anything to do with the repo (the git-dir) at all. They are a special file that has side-effects on git actions when it's present in a working tree. Whenever a .gitignore file is in your working tree (wether it's tracked by your repo or not), it will affect various actions you perform with git using that working tree. Regardless of whether the repo (git-dir) you're working with is bare or not.

Comment: @Chris

`[Start session]` `% cat .gitignore`                                      
file.txt
`% git --git-dir ../bare.git --work-tree=. status`     
On branch master
No commits yet
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
 .gitignore
`% git --git-dir ../bare.git --work-tree=. add file.txt`
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
file.txt
`% grep bare ../bare.git/config`
 bare = true

`[End session]`

Comment: @MarcelBesixdouze, I am familiar with the code of conduct and I don't believe telling somebody that they're wrong violates it. But I'm sorry if you feel condescended to. The workflow you have described affects _a working copy_, not the bare repository. Note also that the question here is about ignoring tracked files. Git's ignore system has no effect on tracked files. Since bare repositories only contain tracked data, the concept of ignoring files doesn't apply to them. You are correct that `.gitignore` files do not need to be tracked to take effect, but they will never ignore tracked files.

Answer (score 1):

You could put all your PHP files in a separate git repository.

That way you could use it as a submodule where you need to use the PHP files. And as your bare clone has no submodules, you don't need a specific gitignore.

Comment: Depending on the project file/directory structure it might be easier to create a new branch and only merge non-php files into it. This could be automated with an alias for example.

Comment: Good idea, but I didn't want to change by folder hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to use a .gitignore file in the root directory that ignores
> all my php files:
>
> *.php
>
> Can I do it this way?

Yes.

You have to put `.gitignore` in `/foo/public_html`. And the `.gitignore` should look like:

```
*.php
```

configure a remote repository using:

```
git --work-tree=/foo/public_html --git-dir=/foo/root.git remote add origin <url>
```

push using:

```
git --work-tree=/foo/public_html --git-dir=/foo/root.git push origin
```

To clone the repository, you use something like:

```
git clone --bare <url> /foo/root.git
```

In my case, I am using a bare repo to manage my dotfiles.

### Where to put the `.gitignore` file (in case of a bare repo)?

We put the `.gitignore` fine in the `--work-tree`.

Let's look at the following example:

```
git --git-dir=/media/blueray/WDPurple/dotfiles --work-tree=$HOME
```

Here, the work tree is `$HOME`. So, you put the `.gitignore` file in `$HOME`.